# Temporarily Disable SeekBar

Tags: android, seekbar, seek

I'm Working on an application that makes a network call to a controller to change light levels depending on a seek bar in the app.  It works very well but if the user slides the seek bar like crazy it freezes the app and I get a force close.

To get around this I need to disable the use of the seek bar while an Async Task does some business, once this Async task is finished I will re enable the seek bar.  Im using an onTouch listener for the seek bar watching for the ACTION_UP event then I trigger an Async task so I cant disable Clickable.

Any ideas?  Thanks for reading.

Comment: Can't you just disable the `SeekBar`? I mean `setEnabled(false)`.